# How do you remove an ambiguous column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

There are many questions similar to this that are asking a different question with regard to avoid duplicate columns **in a join**; that is not what I am asking here.

Given that I *already* have a DataFrame with ambiguous columns, how do I remove a *specific* column?

For example, given:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
        [1, 0.0, "ext-0.0"],
        [1, 1.0, "ext-1.0"],
        [2, 1.0, "ext-2.0"],
        [3, 2.0, "ext-3.0"],
        [4, 3.0, "ext-4.0"],
    ]),
    StructType([
        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("shared", DoubleType(), True),
        StructField("shared", StringType(), True),
    ])
)
```

I wish to retain only the numeric columns.

However, attempting to do something like `df.select("id", "shared").show()` results in:

```
raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "Reference 'shared' is ambiguous, could be: shared, shared.;"
```

Many related solution to this problem are simply 'avoid ever getting into this situation', eg. by using `['joinkey']` instead of `a.joinkey = b.joinkey` on the join. I reiterate that this is not the situation here; this relates to a dataframe that has already been converted into this form.

The metadata from the DF disambiguates these columns:

```
$ df.dtypes
[('id', 'int'), ('shared', 'double'), ('shared', 'string')]

$ df.schema
StructType(List(StructField(id,IntegerType,true),StructField(shared,DoubleType,true),StructField(shared,StringType,true)))
```

So the data *is* retained internally... I just can't see how to use it.

How do I pick one column over the other?

I expected to be able to use, eg. `col('shared#11')` or similar... but there is nothing like that I can see?

Is this simply not possible in spark?

To answer this question, I would ask, please post either a) a working code snippet that solves the problem above, or b) link to something official from the spark developers that this simply isn't supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest solution to this problem is to rename using `df.toDF(...<new-col-names>...)`, but if you don't wanted to change the column name then group the duplicated columns by their type as `struct<type1, type2>` as below-

> Please note that below solution is written in scala, but logically similar code can be implemented in python. Also this solution will work for all duplicate columns in the dataframe-

### 1. Load the test data

```scala
    val df = Seq((1, 2.0, "shared")).toDF("id", "shared", "shared")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+------+------+
      * |id |shared|shared|
      * +---+------+------+
      * |1  |2.0   |shared|
      * +---+------+------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
      * |-- shared: double (nullable = false)
      * |-- shared: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### 2. get all the duplicated column names

```scala
    // 1. get all the duplicated column names
    val findDupCols = (cols: Array[String]) => cols.map((_ , 1)).groupBy(_._1).filter(_._2.length > 1).keys.toSeq
    val dupCols = findDupCols(df.columns)
    println(dupCols.mkString(", "))
    // shared
```

### 3. rename duplicate cols like `shared => shared:string, shared:int`, without touching the other column names

```scala
    val renamedDF = df
      // 2 rename duplicate cols like shared => shared:string, shared:int
      .toDF(df.schema
        .map{case StructField(name, dt, _, _) =>
          if(dupCols.contains(name)) s"$name:${dt.simpleString}" else name}: _*)
```

### 3. create struct of all cols

```scala
    // 3. create struct of all cols
    val structCols = df.schema.map(f => f.name -> f  ).groupBy(_._1)
      .map{case(name, seq) =>
        if (seq.length > 1)
          struct(
            seq.map { case (_, StructField(fName, dt, _, _)) =>
              expr(s"`$fName:${dt.simpleString}` as ${dt.simpleString}")
            }: _*
          ).as(name)
        else col(name)
      }.toSeq
     val structDF = renamedDF.select(structCols: _*)

    structDF.show(false)
    structDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +-------------+---+
      * |shared       |id |
      * +-------------+---+
      * |[2.0, shared]|1  |
      * +-------------+---+
      *
      * root
      * |-- shared: struct (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- double: double (nullable = false)
      * |    |-- string: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
      */
```

### 4. get column by their type using `<column_name>.<datatype>`

```scala
    // Use the dataframe without losing any columns
    structDF.selectExpr("id", "shared.double as shared").show(false)
    /**
      * +---+------+
      * |id |shared|
      * +---+------+
      * |1  |2.0   |
      * +---+------+
      */
```

Hope this is useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is possible by replacing the schema using `.rdd.toDf()` on the dataframe.

However, I'll still accept any answer that is less convoluted and annoying than the one below:

```
import random
import string
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, LongType

def makeId():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(6))

def makeUnique(column):
    return "%s---%s" % (column.name, makeId())

def makeNormal(column):
    return column.name.split("---")[0]

unique_schema = list(map(makeUnique, df.schema))
df_unique = df.rdd.toDF(schema=unique_schema)
df_unique.show()

numeric_cols = filter(lambda c: c.dataType.__class__ in [LongType, DoubleType], df_unique.schema)
numeric_col_names = list(map(lambda c: c.name, numeric_cols))
df_filtered = df_unique.select(*numeric_col_names)
df_filtered.show()

normal_schema = list(map(makeNormal, df_filtered.schema))
df_fixed = df_filtered.rdd.toDF(schema=normal_schema)
df_fixed.show()
```

Gives:

```
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|id---chjruu|shared---aqboua|shared---ehjxor|
+-----------+---------------+---------------+
|          1|            0.0|        ext-0.0|
|          1|            1.0|        ext-1.0|
|          2|            1.0|        ext-2.0|
|          3|            2.0|        ext-3.0|
|          4|            3.0|        ext-4.0|
+-----------+---------------+---------------+

+-----------+---------------+
|id---chjruu|shared---aqboua|
+-----------+---------------+
|          1|            0.0|
|          1|            1.0|
|          2|            1.0|
|          3|            2.0|
|          4|            3.0|
+-----------+---------------+

+---+------+
| id|shared|
+---+------+
|  1|   0.0|
|  1|   1.0|
|  2|   1.0|
|  3|   2.0|
|  4|   3.0|
+---+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Simply rename the columns (in order) and then do whatever you wanted to do!

```
renamed_df = df.toDF("id", "shared_double", "shared_string")
```